# Passing a JSON to Scenario Outline

Tags: karate

https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/554

I have a multirow JSON, I would like to iterate for each row using Scenario outline

It is working if I call by the row number, i am using a dynamic JSON file

Data.json

```
[
{
    "address": {
        "addressLine1": "ttes",
        "addressLine2": "Test"
    },
    "name": {
        "firstName": "TEST",
        "lastName": "TEST"
    },
    "phone": {
        "phoneExtension": "1234",
        "phoneNumber": "999999999"
    },
    "email": {
        "emailAddress": "TEST@TEST.com"
    }
},
{
    "address": {
        "addressLine1": "ttes1",
        "addressLine2": "Test1"
    },
    "name": {
        "firstName": "TEST1",
        "lastName": "TEST1"
    },
    "phone": {
        "phoneExtension": "1234",
        "phoneNumber": "999999999"
    },
    "email": {
        "emailAddress": "TEST@TEST1.com"
    }
}]
```

Working if

```
Feature: Read from File

Background:
* def Testdata = read('Data.json')

Scenario Outline: [1] Test with multiple records on JSON

Given url_stg
And path 'test','test' 
And request Testdata[0]
When method POST  

Examples:
|Testdata   |
```

Working for Testdata[0]. I have dynamic json, I am looking for a way to iterate through the json autoamtically.

My request body should be one row from JSON like :

```
{
"address": {
    "addressLine1": "ttes1",
    "addressLine2": "Test1",

},
"name": {
    "firstName": "TEST1",
    "lastName": "TEST1",

},
"phone": {
    "phoneExtension": "1234",
    "phoneNumber": "999999999",
},
"email": {
    "emailAddress": "TEST@TEST1.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be easier in the next version, see this ticket: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/717#issuecomment-489339287

So if you can build from source and test that would help.

For now you have to do this:

```
And request { address: <address>, name: <name>, phone: <phone>, email: <email> }
```